# ListBoxItem twice the normal size

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have created a simple `ListBox` on the main page but the items added have too much vertical spacing by default (as if an item height is twice what it should be). I have tried changing `DataTemplate` as well as applying 0 margin/padding to `ItemContainerStyle` without any success.

Which property is affecting the height of the `ListBoxItem` on how to size it to content? Changing font family has no effect either.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using for `ListBox.ItemTemplate` as the children in there determine the overall height of each item.

Comment: This is irrelevant as wizard generated code with a simple `ListBox` and a few items reproduces the issue. I have tried resolving the problem with a custom `DataTemplate` but even without one the problem still shows. Thanks!

Comment: @wpfwannabe even if it's created by default you can still show us what it is that you're seeing and an example of what you want it to be like instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the space between where your item row ends and the next row begins.

For wizard generated code:

```
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
```

is saying that the row height is 78 with a 17 pixel gap between rows.

The easiest way to examin what is going on is put some colored borders behind the elements. I have done that below. Changng the heights, or margins then is clearly obvious what space belongs to what element:

```
        <!--ContentPanel contains ListBox and ListBox ItemTemplate. Place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged" Background="Red">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                        <Border Background="Yellow">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="Blue">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: OK, my sincere apologies. This was plain silliness on my part. My `ListBox` entries are plain strings and for some reason each and every one of them had a new line appended. This was causing a double line height. Thanks for your efforts though.